# Non-Websocket Socket.io clients for benchmarking

Tags: node.js, socket.io, benchmarking

There are a bunch of Socket.io client implementations out there in e.g. Java (see [Java socket.io client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783086)), that seem to exclusively support the `Websocket` protocol.

For benchmarking the server performance of other protocols - and I'm particularly interested in `htmlfile` as it will be used by IE browsers < 10, unless I enable Flash, which I'm not sure I'll do, as [socket.io transport 'flashsocket' takes 5 seconds to start on IE 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423797) - is there any Socket.io client available that would allow benchmarking of the server?

I don't care too much what OS or programming language it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's
https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client

In addition to `WebSocket`, it only does `XHR`, and that feature is currently considered to be in beta:

> Status: Connecting with Websocket is production ready. XHR is in beta.

Light testing `xhr polling` seems to support the claim that it is not production ready yet. I had a bunch of disconnects without subsequent reconnects. This was when testing a few hundred client instances simultaneously in one JVM. As there were errors in the server log, I guess it's the client.

One more guess: As the connection drops are so frequent, and the load on the server is so much higher compared to WebSockets, I wonder whether this client's 'xhr polling' does not do HTTP Keepalive, that would explain a lot... Will check as soon as time permits.

Using `WebSocket`, I could do 1000 instances per JVM (probably more) and 5000 instances (5 JVMs x 1000 instances each) per machine (probably more, too) without issues.

And apparently

> it's easy to write your own transport

Will check this out.

Answer (score 0):

It should also be easy to create your own by

- sniffing on a browser <-> socket.io session (On Windows, that's [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/))
- copying the code from [one of the official socket.io tests](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/master/test/transports.htmlfile.test.js)