# How to identify the open-save-cancel dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jakarta-ee

In my application, I have a link named "Export to PDF". On click of that link I will submit a form and I am writing PDF files to that response object which would show modal-dialog in the browser (example-image below)

[image]

**Requirement is to show an progress-bar using jQuery which would stop once this dialog box pops-up.** Please tell how to identify this and start/stop animation. Please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get that kind of event from the brower.
In the other hand you do know when the conversion to PDF ends right ?

Personally I would use socket.io to get a nice progress bar.
Here is an [example app](https://github.com/3on/socket.io-on-dotcloud) of a progress bar updated with socket.io.

But from the wonderful world of java you probably just be better doing a [long polling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/simple-long-polling-example-code).

Comment: Thanks. But it dont suit my requirement. Am using struts-jquery combination. Is there not any other possibility ? only to go for third party tools ??

Comment: They a re plenty of ways http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801014/socket-io-xhr-polling-vs-flashsocket-and-websocket this is one.